# Should I transform the response variable prior to variable selection in OLS?

Tags: regression, modeling, feature-selection, data-transformation

I am trying to conduct a standard ordinary linear regression analysis on a example data set. Observing the data, my response variable is right skewed; a log transformation seems to make the histogram of my response variable approximately symmetric. In this case, should I log transform my response variable prior to conducting a best subset procedure on the explanatory variable candidates? or, should I conduct best subset procedure first and then transform my response variable?

Comment: The typical assumption about normality in OLS is only about the errors, not the response variable. How do your errors look? It’s complicated to talk about $\mathbb{E}[f(Y\vert X=x)]$. A transformation isn’t ideal, especially if your errors are normal.

Comment: The residual plot of $e_{i} vs. \hat{Y}_i$ shows a slight curvature, and the constant variance assumption is not met.